# How Do I Input Message Data Into a DataFrame Using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame:

| name | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | 09:30 | 10:00 |
| Smith | 10:00 | 10:30 |
| Green | 10:30 | 11:00 |

I would like to add some message data as a appointment message:

```
Hello {name}. Your appointment will be held on {time_start} until {time_end}. Enjoy your day!
```

The message will be a new column in the DataFrame as shown below:

| name | time_start | time_end | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | 09:30 | 10:00 | Hello Albert. Your appointment will be held on 09:30 until 10:00. Enjoy your day! |
| Smith | 10:00 | 10:30 | Hello Smith. Your appointment will be held on 10:00 until 10:30. Enjoy your day! |
| Green | 10:30 | 11:00 | Hello Green. Your appointment will be held on 10:30 until 11:00. Enjoy your day! |

Can you help me solve this problem using pandas?

Comment: Simple string concatenation like [this answer](/a/11858532) `df['message'] = "Hello " + df['name'] + ". Your appointment will be held on " + df['time_start'] + " until " + df['time_end'] + ". Enjoy your day!"`

Comment: Or any of the many options of [this answer](/a/54298586) `df['message'] = df.agg(lambda x: f"Hello {x['name']}. Your appointment will be held on {x['time_start']} until {x['time_end']}. Enjoy your day!", axis=1)`

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. Much appreciated